# Trello preview for markdown outcome?

Tags: trello, markdown

When composing Trello card content using markdown syntax, I need to see the preview of the outcome content similarly to how we do here on Stack Exchange.

Is it possible and how to add that?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in here:

https://dillinger.io/

and then copy the markdown into Trello once you are done